# Selection of CRC-16-CCITT

Tags: crc

Cyclic redundancy checks are used often, and works well with proper config. The ITU's ("*CCIT*") CRC gets used a lot -

- Ref - [CRC16-CCITT Reference - Joe Geluso](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/crc16-ccitt.html#addendum-2)

Why are the ITU's CRC values used so frequently? A common 'default' found, so to speak, just curious as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial 0x11021 is used for floppy disks. Part of the reason for choosing that polynomial is that there are only three 1 bits in 0x1021, which simplifies hardware based CRC calculations. This is also true for 0x10007 (FOP-16) and 0x14003 (CRC16, CRC16-IBM), so I'm not sure why 0x11021 was chosen versus the other two somewhat common ones with only three 1 bits in the lower 16 bits.

0x11021 is also used for XMODEM (a serial file transfer program for old computers), which is typically implemented in software, where the number of 1 bits in the polynomial doesn't matter, but may have been chosen since it was used for floppy disks.

0x11021 is the product of two prime polynomials: 0xf01f and 0x3. The 0x3 (x+1) will detect any odd number of bit errors, and it's 2 bit error detection is good for up to 32751 data bits + 16 crc bits = 32767 bits, good enough for floppy disk sector sizes 128, 256, 512, and 1024 bytes (could also be used for 2048 bytes, but I don't recall a floppy disk with a 2048 byte sector size). I'm not aware of any advantage in the choice of a polynomial for single burst error detection. Some polynomials would be better for single burst error correction, but single burst correction isn't common.

The two other polynomials I mentioned are similar, 0x10007 = 0xfffd * 0x3 , 0x14003 = 0xc001 * 0x3.

Comment: my goodness thank you rcgldr this is a great answer, more than I could have ever hoped to find. And excellent future reference to share here, thank you!!